# Longest repeated odd number

Tags: javascript, arrays, custom-functions-excel

Consider:

```
let N = 12
let arr = [1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1]
```

Your task is to find the maximum number of times an odd number is continuously repeated in the array.

What is the approach for this?

This is the hint:

1 is repeated 4 times from index 0 to index 3 → 4 times

2 is repeated 5 times from index 4 to index 8 → 5 times

1 is repeated 3 times from index 9 to index 11 → 3 times

The odd numbers in array are 1s.

1 occurs 4 times and 3 times continuously, so 4 is the maximum number of times an odd number is continuously repeated in this array.

```
function longestRepeatedOdd(N, array) {

    // Write code here

    let count = 0;
    for (let i = 0; i <= array.length-1; i++){
        if (array[i] % 2 !== 0){
            count++
        }else if (array[i] % 2 === 0){
            break;
        }
    }
    console.log(count)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your answer is definitely valid. Just replace *break* with *continue*.

```js
function longestRepeatedOdd(N, array) {
    //write code here
    let count = 0; 
    for (let i = 0; i <= array.length-1; i++){
        if (array[i] % 2 !== 0){
            count++
        }else if (array[i] % 2 === 0){
            continue;
        }    
    }
    return count
}
```

Comment: bro check the hint i want only highest number of repeating  not all

Answer (score 0):

Try `reduce` and creating a JavaScript object that reports its value:

```
const count = arr.reduce((accumulator, value) => {
  return {...accumulator, [value]: (accumulator[value] || 0) + 1};
}, {});

Object { 1: 7, 2: 5 }
console.log(count);
```

Number one repeated 7 times and number two 5 times.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`Array.reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) to keep track of the current run of odd numbers and the maximum.

We use an accumulator value with a `max` and `current` field, the current field the current run of odd numbers and the max field is the longest run.

If the current run exceeds the max we set the max to this value.

```js
function longestRepeatedOdd(arr) {
    return arr.reduce((acc, n, idx) => {
        acc.current = (n === arr[idx - 1] ? acc.current: 0) + (n % 2);
        acc.max = (acc.current > acc.max) ? acc.current: acc.max;
        return acc;
    }, { max: 0, current: 0 }).max;
}

const inputs = [
    [1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1],
    [7, 7, 4, 4, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 4, 3],
    [1, 2, 2, 2]
]

inputs.forEach((input, idx) => {
    console.log(`Test input #${idx + 1} result:`, longestRepeatedOdd(input))
})
```